# Built-in way to use sticky list headers and indexable lists like IOS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Does Android 4.0 have any built-in way to use sticky list headers and indexable lists? I've found the following projects:

1. [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)
2. [IndexableListView](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView)

... but both are separate and I need to follow best practice.

Comment: Hello Noman, If you got answer for this question please give me solution. It will be useful to me in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ListView` (Or rather, its adapter) is already indexable with the `SectionIndexer` interface. I have had no trouble extending `StickyListHeadersBaseAdapter` and implementing `SectionIndexer`. Enable the `fastScroll` in the XML for the list, and drag the scroll handle. There are numerous guides on how to use the `SectionIndexer` interface

Comment: Ok so u mean For StickyListHeader there is no built in way to implement it . i m asking because i want to follow best practice of android.and can u edit your answer with one guide for SectionIndexer.actuly the best one.:)